# Processing - Is there a way to check where a mouse is being clicked on a generated sphere?

Tags: processing

in the development program "Processing" -- Is there a way to check where a mouse is being clicked on a generated sphere?

I've got a map of Earth on a sphere and I want to know where a user clicks on the sphere so I can map it to a city.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Mathematics is the answer. I hope you're good at it, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dist()](https://processing.org/reference/dist_.html), which calculates the distance between 2 2-d positions.

This code should do the trick:

```
void setup(){
    size(500, 500);
}

int x = 250;
int y = 250;
int diameter = 100;

void draw(){
    background(200);
    if(dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y) < diameter / 2) fill(250);
    else fill(0);

    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
}
```